# How can I type hint arbitrary generic type aliases in Python?

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I've implemented a Python function, which takes a generic type alias, from which it extracts the origin and arguments for further processing.

Now I want to use a static type checker (MyPy) and want to provide a type hint for the `alias` argument.
One idea would be to use the [`types.GenericAlias`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.GenericAlias) class:

```py
import typing
from types import GenericAlias


def foo(alias: GenericAlias):
    origin = typing.get_origin(alias)
    args = typing.get_args(alias)
    ...
```

Now I want to use a [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) type alias as an argument for the function:

```py
x = typing.Callable[[int, int], float]
foo(x)
```

Unfortunately, MyPy now reports an error:

```
Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "object"; expected "GenericAlias"
```

The same happens when I use `type` instead of `GenericAlias` as the type hint for `alias`.

Investigating further, I get the following:

```
>>> isinstance(x, type)
False
>>> isinstance(x, GenericAlias)
False
>>> type(x)
<class 'typing._CallableGenericAlias'>
>>> isinstance(x, typing._CallableGenericAlias)
True
```

So, apparently, neither `type` nor `GenericAlias` cover the generic type alias when using `Callable` and I can't use them to type hint generic type aliases in general.
Is there anything else that I can use, or am I stuck with using [`Any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any)?

I would also be interested in an explanation for why `typing._CallableGenericAlias` is not a subtype of `types.GenericAlias`.

Comment: I think this is an error, but I am not sure, whether `mypy` or `typeshed` is responsible. The `Callable.__class_getitem__` method clearly returns an instance of `typing._CallableGenericAlias`, which is clearly a subclass of `GenericAlias`. But it seems that the team views the whole `GenericAlias` situation with somewhat of a "meh"-approach, judging from [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/13637). IMO this at least warrants a question in their issue tracker about how they propose to annotate something that accepts an instance of a `Callable` generic alias.

Comment: *which is clearly a subclass of GenericAlias.* - Right, I thought so as well. But somehow, `issubclass(typing._CallableGenericAlias, GenericAlias)` evaluates to `False`?